# How do I execute a Thread Group within another Thread Group?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, jmx

I have a scenario in which I have to register a number of users and than run parallel with threads as the number of registered users and execute same set of actions by all the users in parallel. for this I have a jmx with few actions that should happened only once (in a setup thread with one thread count) and another thread group that runs with say 5 threads which is the number of the previously registered users, and I execute some operations using these users.
Now I want  execute this whole scenario in parallel using 5 threads.

How do I come about doing this?

I used the include controller but thread groups are not executed as expected, I don't get 25 iterations for the actions that happen in a 5 threads group in the included jmx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not precisely sure what you're doing, and I know little of jmx, but here's a couple of ideas.  One (or both) might be relevant.

The first one is that your threads might be sharing an instance field.  If they have a common counter, for instance, you will do something 5 times rather than 25 times.  Make sure your common variables (instance and class fields) are properly synchronized.  Use local variables whenever possible.  You *must* use them when their value applies to *each* thread rather than all threads.

The second is that you might be displaying results--or event stopping the program--before all threads have done their work.  It's worst on single-core machines, but threads can and do run in any order imaginable, and in a few orders that are not.  They can run one at a time, with the one started last running first.  One can stop in the middle, and let all the other run to completion, then start up again.  A bunch can run simultaneously (on different cores or swapping rapidly) while others do nothing.

I'd suggest putting in a bunch of logging/output statements (System.out.println is good enough) and seeing for yourself what's happening.  It'll take you a while to make sense of your output, but once you do, you'll be able to start bringing things under control.